# Who is the woman who took over the clean up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

At the beginning of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*,

> a heavy set Caucasian woman with grey hair walked into a site where alien debris was being cleaned up.  The woman announced that she was taking over the clean-up project on behalf of authorized parties, and that the other crew at the site had to vacate the premises and return any exotic materials.

**What is the woman's name?  And what is her character's back story?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character is credited as [Anne Marie Hoag](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2250912/).

She is the Director of the Department of Damage Control in the MCU.
There may be more regarding her character depending on the status of the Damage Control TV show.

You can read more about Damage Control in the Damage Control comics, or if you want to look up Wiki links [such as this](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Control_(Earth-616)).

In the comics, Anne Marie Hoag is the founder of Damage Control.

Comment: Oldsters like me also recognized her as Tyne Daly, who played one of the title characters in "Cagney and Lacey" and was in the first, or was it the second, Dirty Harry movie.